# Чтение и обработка данных COM порта

Tags: python, com-port

Доброго времени суток уважаемые пользователи!
Я пишу на питоне недавно и исключительно для себя.
Возникла проблема.
Есть устройство работающее через СОМ-порт.
я отправляю на него команды - на что получаю ответы.
вопрос заключается в том, что мне нужно выйти из цикла после того как я получу нужные ответы.
Считывание ответа происходит построчно.
Я предполагаю, что скорее всего неправильно составлена логика цикла.

Вот мой код:

```
    def send_comm(self, serial_port, date_command):
        print(date_command)
        if "NETSCAN" in str(date_command):
            time.sleep(2)
            result = ""
            time_out = 0
            for i in range(3):
                serial_port.write(date_command.encode())
                state_cycle = True
                print(f"Начат проход № '{i}'")
                while state_cycle:
                    read_data = serial_port.readline()
                    start_cycle = time.time()
                    print(read_data)
                    if "ERROR" in str(read_data):
                        result = result + str(read_data).replace("\r\n", "\n").replace('OK', '') + "\n"
                        self.date_from_cmd = result
                        state_cycle = False
                    elif "NETSCAN" in str(read_data):
                        result = result + str(read_data).replace("\r\n", "\n").replace('OK', '') + "\n"
                        self.date_from_cmd = result
                    else:
                        state_cycle = True
                        end_cycle = time.time()
                        time_out = time_out + (end_cycle-start_cycle)
                        print(str(round(time_out, 2)) + " sec")
                        if time_out == 130:
                            state_cycle = False
                            result = result + "+CME ERROR: 31"
                            self.date_from_cmd = result
                print(f"Закончен проход № '{i}'")
                time.sleep(1)
        else:
            serial_port.write(str(date_command).encode())
            time.sleep(2)

        if "AT^NETSCAN=20,-110,3" in date_command:
         передаем данные в другую функцию для формирования отчета и записи в файл.
        elif "AT^NETSCAN=20,-110,1" in date_command:
            передаем данные в другую функцию для формирования отчета и записи в файл.
        elif "AT^NETSCAN=20,-110,0" in date_command:
          передаем данные в другую функцию для формирования отчета и записи в файл.
```

Вот в таком виде приходят строки в переменную **read_data**

```
b'\r\n' - это ответ на крайнюю команду о запуске сканирования
b'OK\r\n' - и это тоже ответ.
b''
b''
b'\r\n'
b'^NETSCAN: 114,,,E11,250,02,18,-61,B5EC,100300\r\n'
b'^NETSCAN: 28,,,A8F,250,01,56,-63,1F2D,100300\r\n'
b'^NETSCAN: 42,,,3000,250,99,13,-63,77CA,100300\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'OK\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'^SRVST: 4\r\n'
b''
b''
```

или вот в таком виде.

```
b''
b''
b'+CME ERROR: 31'
b'\r\n'
b'OK\r\n'
b''
b''
```

b''  - пустая строка.

то есть, при запуске сканирования - если данные найдены (как правило что-то в районе 40-80 секунд ожидаем ответа или если данных нет приходит ошибка 31 (тайм-аут).

количество строк
b'^NETSCAN: - может быть разное.

Задача заключается в том, чтобы записать приходящие данные и передать их в файл.
Отсюда я вижу 2 выхода,
1.либо прервать цикл после последней строки b'^NETSCAN: или b'+CME ERROR: 31'
2.запомнить к примеру когда изменялась переменная result последний раз, и если она не обновлялась к примеру 5 секунд - то завершить цикл.

я пробовал итеррировать строки через tee , next - не получается.
реализацию 1 и 2 выхода я банально не могу сообразить как это реализовать.

Спасибо за помощь или хотя бы подсказки.

Comment: А две пустые строки всегда между сообщениями?

Comment: нет. их там может быть 40, 80,90 это для примера 2 строки. и после если не прерывать , то бесконечное количество

Comment: Если установить flag после завершения первой группы пробелов, а при появлении второй и если флаг установлен, то state_cycle = False?

Comment: как работает в целом алгоритм сейчас: отправляю команду сканирования, получаю пустую строку, замет ок, затем пошли пустые строки, затем построчно пошло сыпаться нетскан.... и если поставить state_cycle = False в условии elif "NETSCAN" in str(read_data): то при получении строк ^NESCAN... он заверашет цикл for

Comment: я могу вам записать видео работы алгоритма, если вам это необходимо. просто бьюсь 3 дня уже.

Comment: Давайте, посмотрю.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VrraOcd9V8ddl69yQY42WJCmElhnxyG7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Gruvi, зачем вы удалили вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466277/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2 ?

Comment: @Nick, удалил, потому, что предыдущий раз, ни кто не помог, он просто провисел. Но теперь 
 восстановил тему, если есть желание помочь, можно перейти в телеграмм или дискорд, для более детального обсуждения вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ найден!
заключался в ведении еще одного условия логического, до которого я не мог дойти очень долго

```
elif prev_comm == "NETSCAN" and not ("NETSCAN" in str(read_data)):
    state_cycle = False
```