# Помощь в инициализации потока основного окна и дополнительных рабочих потоков

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, многопоточность, qthread

Было нарисовано в PyQt5 основное окно, в котором есть 2 `Qtextedit'a`, в которые должны выводиться строки (своего рода лог) о результатах работы устройств которые работают через СОМ-порты, устройства 2 и они работают параллельно (каждый в своем потоке).
Без дестопной части, всё работает хорошо, а вот с ней, не работает ничего.
Прошу помощи в решении этой проблемы, в том числе и на мат. основе.
Код работы main прилагаю.
если нужно подробно рассказать о проекте, готов выйти в телеграмм, дискорд, куда угодно.

```
import reo_main_window
import dialog_adress
import scanclass
import time
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import sys
from threading import Thread


"""
    Функция "scanttyusb" сканирует порты и возвращает номера портов
    к которым подключены нужные устройства
"""
def scan_ttyusb():
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    result = ""
    for text in ports:
        if 'Pcui' in text[1]:
            txt = text[0]
            result = result + txt + ','
            device_port = result

    return device_port.split(",")

"""
    Функция "runing_scan" создает экземпляр класса помещая в него нужные значения переменных
"""
def runing_scan(number_port):
    scan = scanclass.ScanningReo("serial_port", "date_from_cmd", "date_command", "name_freq", "name_dev")
    print(number_port)
    opn_srl_prt = scan.open_serial_port(number_port)
    opn_srl_prt.close()
    opn_srl_prt = scan.open_serial_port(number_port)
    # print(opn_srl_prt)
    id_dev = scan.device_identification(opn_srl_prt)
    print(id_dev)
    if "120" in id_dev:
        ui.label_plate_1.setText(f"{id_dev}")
        date_command = [f'"AT^SYSCFGEX\r"', "AT^NETSCAN\r",
                        f'"AT^SYSCFGEX=\r"', "AT^NETSCAN\r",
                        "STOP"
                        ]

    elif "821" in id_dev:
        ui.label_plate_2.setText(f"{id_dev}")
        date_command = [f'"AT^SYSCFGEX\r"', "AT^NETSCAN\r",
                        f'"AT^SYSCFGEX=\r"', "AT^NETSCAN\r",
                        "STOP"
                        ]

    for i in date_command:
        if "SYSCFGEX" in i:
            i = i.strip('"')
            time.sleep(2)
        while scan.send_comm(opn_srl_prt, i) == "STOP":
            message_handler(id_dev, msg=date_command)
            time.sleep(2)

"""
    Функция "run_th" запускает потоки с экземплярами класса
"""
def run_th():
    plate1 = scan_ttyusb()[0]
    plate2 = scan_ttyusb()[1]
    thread1 = Thread(target=runing_scan, args=[plate1])
    thread2 = Thread(target=runing_scan, args=[plate2])

    start = time.time()
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    end = time.time()
    print("Время работы потока 1: " + time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(end - start)))
    thread2.join()
    end2 = time.time()
    print("Время работы потока 2: " + time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(end2 - start)))

"""
    Функция "message_handler" обрабатывает поступающие сообщения и выводит их в ui.textEdit
"""
def message_handler(id_dev, msg):
    if "120" in id_dev:
        if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 1")
        if "Начат" or "Закончен" in msg:
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append(f"{msg}")
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append(f"{msg}")
        if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 2")
        if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 3")
    if "821" in id_dev:
        if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 1")
        if "Начат" or "Закончен" in msg:
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append(f"{msg}")
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append(f"{msg}")
        if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 2")
        if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
            ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 3")

        return msg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Создание приложения
    app = reo_main_window.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Создание формы главного окна и инициализация Ui
    main_window = reo_main_window.QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = reo_main_window.Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(main_window)
    main_window.show()
    main_window.setFixedSize(680, 572)


    # Создание формы диалога внесения адреса и инициализация uid
    dialog = dialog_adress.QtWidgets.QWidget()
    uid = dialog_adress.Ui_Form_dialog_adress()
    uid.setupUi(dialog)
    # dialog.show()
    dialog.setFixedSize(440, 161)

    # Вызов кнопки "Старт"
    ui.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(run_th)

    # Запуск основного цикла
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не могу проверить ваше приложение и не понимаю некоторых вещей.

Но предложу вам попробовать следующее:

```
import sys
#- import time
#- from threading import Thread

# ??? я не понимаю ваши импорты !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
# ??? import reo_main_window
# ??? import dialog_adress
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

import scanclass                               # ?

import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

        
class Thread(QThread):
    # я предполагаю что вам надо что-то передавать из дополнительного 
    # потока что-то типа object(видимо это список - id_dev) и
    # str (видимо какая-то строка - msg, типа "Начинаю сканирование 2") и
    # str ('Plate 1' или 'Plate 2', на всякий случай, если надо будет)
    # в основном потоке показывать откуда пришли данные    
    updateSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, str, str)                     # !!!  

    def __init__(self, plate, name_thread):
        super().__init__()
        self.number_port = plate
        self.name_thread = name_thread
        print(f'number_port = {self.number_port}; {self.name_thread}') 

    def run(self):                   # runing_scan(number_port):
        scan = scanclass.ScanningReo(
            "serial_port", "date_from_cmd", 
            "date_command", "name_freq", "name_dev")
        print(self.number_port)
        opn_srl_prt = scan.open_serial_port(self.number_port)
        opn_srl_prt.close()
        opn_srl_prt = scan.open_serial_port(self.number_port)
        # print(opn_srl_prt)
        id_dev = scan.device_identification(opn_srl_prt)

        print(id_dev)
        if "120" in id_dev:
#-            ui.label_plate_1.setText(f"{id_dev}")
            self.updateSignal.emit(id_dev, '120', self.name_thread)       # !!! +++
            date_command = [f'"AT^SYSCFGEX\r"', "AT^NETSCAN\r",
                            f'"AT^SYSCFGEX=\r"', "AT^NETSCAN\r",
                            "STOP"]
        elif "821" in id_dev:
#-            ui.label_plate_2.setText(f"{id_dev}")
            self.updateSignal.emit(id_dev, '821', self.name_thread)       # !!! +++
            date_command = [f'"AT^SYSCFGEX\r"', "AT^NETSCAN\r",
                            f'"AT^SYSCFGEX=\r"', "AT^NETSCAN\r",
                            "STOP"]
        for i in date_command:
            if "SYSCFGEX" in i:
                i = i.strip('"')
                self.msleep(1000 * 2)   # 2 сек.
            while scan.send_comm(opn_srl_prt, i) == "STOP":    # ?
                message_handler(id_dev, msg=date_command)
#-                time.sleep(2)
                self.msleep(1000 * 2)                                     # 2 сек.

    def message_handler(id_dev, msg):
        """ Функция "message_handler" обрабатывает поступающие сообщения 
            и выводит их в ui.textEdit
        """
        
        if "120" in id_dev:
            if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
#-                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 1")
                self.updateSignal.emit(
                    id_dev, "120Начинаю сканирование `120` 1", self.name_thread) # !!! +++
                
            if "Начат" or "Закончен" in msg:
#-                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append(f"{msg}")
#-                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append(f"{msg}")
                self.updateSignal.emit(
                    id_dev, "120Начат or Закончен `120`", self.name_thread)     # !!! +++                
                
# ???            if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
# ???                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 2")
# ???            if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
# ???                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 3")
                
        if "821" in id_dev:
            if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
#-                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование `821` 1")
                self.updateSignal.emit(
                    id_dev, "821Начинаю сканирование `821` 1", self.name_thread) # !!! +++
             
            if "Начат" or "Закончен" in msg:
#-                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append(f"{msg}")
#-                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append(f"{msg}")
                self.updateSignal.emit(
                    id_dev, "821Начат or Закончен `821`", self.name_thread)     # !!! +++                
                                
# ???            if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
# ???                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 2")
# ???            if "AT^NETSCAN" in msg:
# ???                ui.textEdit_plate_1.append("Начинаю сканирование 3")
# ???            return msg

        

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
#  модуль Ui_MainWindow надо импортировать 
#  как-то так:
#  from q1461951_name_ui import Ui_MainWindow
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):   
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(self.run_th)

    def run_th(self):
        """ Функция "run_th" запускает потоки с экземплярами класса """
        
        device_port = self.scan_ttyusb()
        plate1 = device_port[0]               # scan_ttyusb()[0]
        plate2 = device_port[1]               # scan_ttyusb()[1]
        
        self.thread_1 = Thread(plate1, 'Plate 1')
        self.thread_1.updateSignal.connect(self.update_thread)    
        self.thread_1.start()
        
        self.thread_2 = Thread(plate2, 'Plate 2')
        self.thread_2.updateSignal.connect(self.update_thread)    
        self.thread_2.start()
  
#        thread1 = Thread(target=runing_scan, args=[plate1])
#        thread2 = Thread(target=runing_scan, args=[plate2])

    def update_thread(self, id_dev, plate, name_thread):
        if name_thread == 'Plate 1':
            if plate == '120':
                self.label_plate_1.setText(f"{id_dev}")
            elif plate[0:3] == '120':
                self.textEdit_plate_1.append(plate[3:])
        elif name_thread == 'Plate 2':
            if plate == '821':
                self.label_plate_2.setText(f"{id_dev}")     
            elif plate[0:3] == '821':
                self.textEdit_plate_1.append(plate[3:])                

    def scan_ttyusb(self):
        """ Функция "scan_ttyusb" сканирует порты и возвращает номера портов
            к которым подключены нужные устройства
        """
        
        ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
        result = ""
        for text in ports:
            if 'Pcui' in text[1]:
                txt = text[0]
                result = result + txt + ','
                device_port = result

        return device_port.split(",")
    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Создание формы главного окна и инициализация Ui
#    main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(main_window)

    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.resize(680, 572)
    main_window.show()
   
#    main_window.setFixedSize(680, 572)
# ???    # Создание формы диалога внесения адреса и инициализация uid dialog_adress
# ???    dialog = QtWidgets.QWidget()
# ???    uid = Ui_Form_dialog_adress()
# ???    uid.setupUi(dialog)
# ???    # dialog.show()
# ???    dialog.setFixedSize(440, 161)
# Вызов кнопки "Старт"
#    ui.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(run_th)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: можете мне написать в телеграмм, я подробнее расскажу или в дискорд ?

Comment: там немного не так, как вы описали, но в ту сторону. напишите мне пожалуйста на @Gruviman в тг

Comment: reo_main_window - это название .ру файла мэин окна приложения. dialog_adress - это окно диалога, которое должно вываливаться, после того, как отработают 2 потока (запрос места нахождения), которое будет использоваться для формирования имени файла

Comment: по факту у меня есть 2 устройства, работающие через СОМ-порты, они работают параллельно каждый в своем потоке (для сокращения времени работы). то есть как должно изначально всё происходить пользователь открывает приложение, кликает по кнопке старт, происходит проверка "подключены устройства или нет" и если да, то получает номер порта, имя устройства и запускает их, добавляя названия в лэйбл 1 и лэйбл 2 соответственно, под которыми находятся text.edit'ы, в которые в свою очередь должны сыпаться строки при работе устройства "начато то-то, завершено то-то и т.д."

Comment: @Gruvi то что вы написали это хорошо, но это все надо писать не в комментариях, а в теле вопроса. Но меня интересует что не так в написанном мною, вы что мой пример не можете запустить?

Comment: С написанной вами информацией файл удалось запустить, Огромное вам спасибо.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как теперь подключить text.Edit' ы и после прекращения работы потоков, чтобы выскакивало диалоговое окно ?

Comment: можете помочь с обновлением text.edit, qlable @Nick ?

Comment: @Gruvi задайте новый вопрос, приложите новый код и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать.